# I cant get all the data from firebase to my Listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I couldnt able to display my data from firebase to my listview in android application. Rather it only shows one data.
Heres the current data of my database:
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqpvw.png)

And this is my java:

```
public class scheduleList extends ArrayAdapter<Schedule> {
private Activity context;
private List<Schedule> scheduleList;

public scheduleList(Activity context, List<Schedule> scheduleList){
    super(context, R.layout.listlayout, scheduleList);
    this.context=context;
    this.scheduleList=scheduleList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listviewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, null, true);

    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewSchedule = (TextView) listviewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewSchedule);

    Schedule schedule = scheduleList.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(schedule.getAppointer());
    textViewSchedule.setText(schedule.getAppointment_schedule());

    return listviewItem;
}}
```

My java file:

```
public class Appointment extends AppCompatActivity {
CalendarView calendarView;
TextView myDate;
private Button btn1;
ListView listViewSchedule;
List<Schedule> scheduleList;
DatabaseReference databaseAppointments;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment);
    databaseAppointments = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("appointment");
    calendarView = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    myDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myDate);
    listViewSchedule=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSchedule);
    scheduleList = new ArrayList<>();
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.appt);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Appointment.this, appointments2.class);
                                    Appointment.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                                }
                            });

    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String date = (i1 + 1) + "/" + i2 + "/" + i;
            myDate.setText(date);
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseAppointments.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            scheduleList.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot scheduleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Schedule schedule = scheduleSnapshot.getValue(Schedule.class);
                scheduleList.add(schedule);
            }
            scheduleList adapter = new scheduleList(Appointment.this, scheduleList);
            listViewSchedule.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

and lastly my xml file containing the listview:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.cs409.instappoint.Appointment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myDate"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select the date"
    android:textColor="#ee912a"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="380dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="320dp">
    </CalendarView>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="#ee912a" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Appointments"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewSchedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/appt"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="120dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_calen"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Appoint now"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Im guessing that the scrollview layout affects the listview but im not sure. Also the listview display whatevers the first on the list.

Comment: try to debug it.print the schedule list in the logcat

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. search example of how to use FirebaseRecylerAdapter with example.